# How does ubuntu find the app name on desktop search?

Tags: unity, launcher

I have installed an open-source software let's say with the name of `foo`. It is installed and I can press the `Windows Key` and `search` for the `foo` and its icon will appear and I can see it on the search.
How about searching it with another key-word? I want to search `bar` and also its icon of the `foo` program appears. Where should I modify to do this? Is it the `desktop entry` file I should modify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit the `Keywords` field in the .desktop file. For example, in the [.desktop file](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/blob/e613330db24a90ab13a12556a606d8ebd65d5fcc/data/com.github.johnfactotum.Foliate.desktop.in#L12) of [Foliate](https://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/) ebook reader it is

```
Keywords=Ebook;Book;EPUB;Viewer;Reader;
```

Foliate would show up when one searches for any of these in the menu/searchbar.

Comment: Here are the different keys (Table 2).
https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html